# How can I remove the labels off my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I just switched to a Dvorak keyboard. The problem is that I don't have a standard keyboard so I can't move the keys around. I don't want to use labels or stickers. I noticed that some of the key's original labels are starting to disappear due to wear. I'd like to remove the labels from all the keys so that it looks similar to [this keyboard](http://www.daskeyboard.com/model-s-ultimate/).

How can I remove the labels without damaging the keyboard?

I'm using a [Microsoft Wireless Comfort Keyboard 1.0a](http://arstechnica.com/hardware/reviews/2005/08/wireless-keyboard-mouse.ars/4).

Comment: Instead of removing the labels, have you considered painting them over in black (assuming the keys are black as in the link)?

Comment: From personal experience, I'd recommend just leaving your keyboard in QWERTY.  Doing so will ensure that you learn Dvorak entirely by touch and will allow you to easily use QWERTY by sight if a need arises for you to use it (such as in games).

Comment: Consider that Dvorak has never been shown to actually be any better than QWERTY. Just keep using QWERTY.

Answer (score 2):

I say get that blank keyboard. You would probably learn to touch type faster with it, sink or swim style:

[image]

http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/keyboards-mice/8396/

Answer (score 2):

I tried different solvents on my Lenovo miix300 keyboard. Results:

Acetone, Solvent-646 (Toluene 50%, butanol 15%, ethanol 10%, etc) damages key's plastic, but there is absolutely no damage to stickers;
Ethyl acetate, kerosine, isopropanol, white spirit - no effect at all.

Damaged keys was repaired by grinding with 600 sandpaper (not polishing, because of not good finger sense). It's not good solution because of hardness of accurately removing many keys (may be on desktop keyboard it will be easier).

So my answer - there is no good solutions :)

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try some different solvents...if you use a strong solvent, be sure to dilute it first, because some solvents will actually melt plastic.

Failing that, I'd try polishing the letters off with a [Dremel](http://www.dremel.com/en-us/AttachmentsAndAccessories/Pages/AttachmentsDetail.aspx?pid=422).

Comment: +1: Using this method is probably the best, but be careful if you try it...  Certain solvents will eat too much plastic away.  I would try this by first adding a small amount of your solvent to a rag and rubbing gently, then go up from there in amount and how hard you rub.

Comment: I was also thinking about using a solvent, but I was hoping someone would know which one I should use.

Comment: @eagle: I'd try some concentrated citrus cleaner first...I don't think that'll melt your keys, at least.  If that doesn't work, try mixing a couple drops of tub & tile cleaner with several drops of water, then use a rag or Q-tip as nicorellius suggested.  You can gradually increase the concentration if it seems like it's not doing anything.  If there's a key you don't use often--like ScrLk or Pause/Break--try that one first.

Answer (score 1):

Nail polish remover should work.  Just don't get any under the keys.

Comment: Nail polish remover is extremely strong and may melt/smooth out the plastic. I strongly suggest spot testing on the bottom of the keyboard first.

Comment: Tried it with my Logitech ultra x keyboard, no luck ;/ It didn't even do anything to the key plastic. Will try with another one and keep u updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try scraping them off with the tip of a nail file.

You could also color over them with a black permanent marker. The labels will probably still be somewhat visible (sorry, I'm not willing to test with my own keyboard), but it'll be better than nothing and very low effort.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all the keys from the keyboard, using a sharp thing as a lever.
2. Place all the keys on a big cardboard, while maintaining their relative position and orientation (preferably loosely glued to the cardboard).
3. Paint the keys with black color or use black gel pen ink.
4. Leave it to dry for 2 days in sun.
5. Plug all keys back at their respective position.